# Is there any way to trace the specific node in ns2 wireless simulation?

Tags: customization, trace, wireless, ns2

I'm generating the trace file of the wireless broadcast simulation by ns2, but I only care about the two specific nodes. How can I only trace these two nodes to reduce the hardware space the result file will take?

I can't fond the solution over the internet...

the part of the code I used is shown below:

```
set ns_          [new Simulation]
set topo         [new Topography]
set tracefile    [open "results.tr" w]
$ns_ trace-all   $tracefile
```

for example, there are 300 nodes in the simulation, but I only want the results of packets sent, received or dropped on node1 and node2. And only trace this kind of information in the result file to save the hardware space.

Comment: May be : https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node205.html : `To enable tracing only on a specific link on a specific node, one may use the command: $node trace-inlink-queue $f $i ;;; $node trace-outlink-queue $f $i` ... Ref. Google, ns2 trace node 2 only : ~280,000 hits !

Comment: Reduce a trace file, example compression : AODV30-30.tr 723MB → `$ xz AODV30-30.tr` → AODV30-30.tr.xz = 16.1MB .

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the "node-config" to config different nodes. For example:

```
    # =============================================
    # settings for node_(0), turn on some of the trace
    $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
        -llType $val(ll) \
        -macType $val(mac) \
        -ifqType $val(ifq) \
        -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
        -antType $val(ant) \
        -propType $val(prop) \
        -phyType $val(netif) \
        -channelType $val(chan) \
        -topoInstance $topo \
        -agentTrace ON \
        -routerTrace ON \
        -macTrace OFF \
        -movementTrace OFF          

        set node_(0) [$ns_ node]    
        $node_(0) random-motion 0       ;# disable random motion

    # ============================================
    # settings for node_(1), turn off all of the trace
    $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
        -llType $val(ll) \
        -macType $val(mac) \
        -ifqType $val(ifq) \
        -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
        -antType $val(ant) \
        -propType $val(prop) \
        -phyType $val(netif) \
        -channelType $val(chan) \
        -topoInstance $topo \
        -agentTrace OFF \
        -routerTrace OFF \
        -macTrace OFF \
        -movementTrace OFF          

        set node_(1) [$ns_ node]    
        $node_(1) random-motion 0       ;# disable random motion
```